# How to install DWScript

Tags: delphi, dwscript

I am trying to install DWScript into Delphi XE4: (I did copy the package files into a DelphiXE4 folder and change the package suffix property to XE4...)

In the packages folder there are 3 files:

```
dwsLibRuntime.dpk
dwsLib.dpk
dwsLibDesignOnly.dpk
```

I manage to install dwsLibRuntime and then dwsLib (although I get a few warnings which I ignore), but then have problems trying to install dwsLibDesignOnly.

Is one meant to install both dwsLib.dpk and dwsLibDesignOnly.dpk, or only one of them?? (They both reference the same Register unit, so it would seem that only one should be installed).

Answer (score 0):

I just installed dws in the following manner (after downloading using svn and creating a new project directory , `\DelphiX4`, copying the four files from `\DelphiXE3`):
When you open dwsLib.dproj you should have (in Project Manager, under ProjectGroup1) dwsLibXE3.bpl as your project.
In Project Options - Description, Change LIB suffix to XE4 and under Usage options select 'DesignTime and Runtime'. Click OK and your project should now be dwsLibXE4.bpl.
Right click on dwsLibXE4.bpl and select Build. (I moved dwsWebUtils.pas from `\Libraries\SimpleServer` to `\Libraries\SymbolsLib` to succeed with the build, adding `\Libraries\SimpleServer` to the search path would be better).
After a successful build right click on dwsLibXE4.bpl again and select 'Install'.
The DWScript group should now be available on the Tool Palette.

Comment: That also works, (maybe better than what I did), but does not answer why dwsLibDesignOnly.dpk package is there